# Is there a way to get a list of all quick settings settings tiles which are there in the panel?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-app-quick-setting

I am trying to mimic the notification shade for my personal learning. Naturally I would need to add quick setting tiles in my app as well. But i am completely unaware of any way to get them. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you tried already?

Comment: @triplem My first instinct was to manually add some tiles to a list and use that to display a GridView. However, that approach is limited since different phones have different quick settings tiles apart from a few standard ones. I can make those common ones into my app but how do I get the other tiles?

Comment: @MohammadYasir How did you finally get it?